# Saving the header of a dataframe to a csv file in pandas

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe in pandas as such

```
Name    Age    Gender
Emily   10     female
Rob     12     male
```

I want to save a csv file from this dataframe so that it looks like so

```
Index     ColumnName
0         Name
1         Age
2         Gender
```

I can't find anything online which tell me how I can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame({"ColumnName": df.columns}).to_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```